# How to "unwrap" a ZoneAwareError?

Tags: angular, zonejs

In my Angular 2 app I have a resolve guard which tries a xhr and throws a custom error if it fails:

```
return this.service.getProduct (id)
    .catch (err => Observable.throw(new MyError(err.message, route, 500, err)));
```

`MyError` is just an extension of `Error`:

```
export class MyError extends Error {

    constructor(message, routeSnapshot, code, err) {
        super(message);
        this.name = 'MyError';
        this.routeSnapshot = routeSnapshot;
        this.code = code;
        this.err = err;
    }

}
```

My global error handler receives an instance of `ZoneAwareError` instead of `MyError`:

```
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    handleError(error) {
        console.log('handling err', error);
        // this prints a ZoneAwareError on the console
    }

}
```

Is `error` really supposed to be wrapped in `ZoneAwareError`? How do I unwrap it to get `MyError` back? Is it safe to rely on the `error.rejection` property? (Because I can see `MyError` there).

**=== Edit:**

Ok, I just discovered that Angular wraps errors in different sub-types of `Error`, not only `ZoneAwareError`. So far I have this function to unwrap them, but it feels a bit hacky:

```
function unwrap (err) {
    let res = err.rejection ? err.rejection : err;

    while (res.originalError) {
        res = res.originalError;
    }
    res.name = res.name || 'unknown';
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see how unwrapping is done in Angular itself:  [angular/modules/@angular/core/src/error_handler.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/745e10e6d2ea9097b7ec650ae54cea91e3d193f2/modules/%40angular/core/src/error_handler.ts), however they don't seem to handle `rejection` (which is quite usefull) in any way so i use the following before unwrapping:

```
    if(error.hasOwnProperty('rejection'))
    {
        error = error.rejection;
    }
```

[UncaughtPromiseError](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/ac7b04697b39acce4c3aa11f9d29c9004ed07ddb/lib/zone.ts#L983) interface in zone.js.